# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'scheduler'

Tags: python-2.7

Recently, I am interesting in Python language, so I try to test the following 
codes.

```
import sched
import time

scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def print_event(name, start):
    now = time.time()
    elapsed = int(now - start)
    print 'EVENT: %s elapsed=%s name=%s' % (time.ctime(now), elapsed, name)

start = time.time()
print 'START:', time.ctime(start)
scheduler.enter(2, 1, print_event, ('first', start))
scheduler.enter(3, 1, print_event, ('second', start))

scheduler.run()
```

After testing I got error as below:

calvin@calvin-K42Jv:/usr/local/myprjs/Python$ python sched3.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sched3.py", line 1, in 
    import sched
  File "/usr/local/myprjs/Python/sched.py", line 2, in 
    s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'scheduler'

Comment: sched.scheduler should maybe be scheduler.sched ?

Comment: I get /usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in ''. Please provide a [mcve]